# Super slow internet speeds ubuntu server

Tags: networking, server, usb

The USB Wifi Dongle is
Belkin Components f7D2101 802.11n Surf & Share Wireless Adapter v1000 [Realtek RTL8192SU]

After 2 days I managed to get that working with ubuntu server. However, even plugged in with ethernet cable I still only get 70mbits/s download speed. Compared to windows on the same machine I was getting 400+.

I have tried other's solutions like,

`sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf` and lowering to 2, etc.

`sudo apt remove backport-iwlwifi-dkms` (Someone said it could be the issue)

`sudo nano /etc/gai.conf`  On the line`precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  100` removed the #

Not sure what else I can try.

```
wlxc05627039dc1  Scan completed :
      Cell 01 - Address: 60:32:B1:A6:15:CB
                ESSID:"TP-Link_15CC"
                Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
                Mode:Master
                Frequency:2.442 GHz (Channel 7)
                Encryption key:on
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                          24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                          12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                Extra:rsn_ie=30140100000fac040100000fac040100000fac020c00
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : CCMP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: Unknown: DD1D0050F204104A0001101044000102103C0001031049000600372A000120
                Signal level=100/100
```

The usb adapter says it supports up to 300mbs, but like i said its even with the wired connection.

Answer (score 0):

> Frequency:2.442 GHz (Channel 7)

You are very unlikely to get top speeds on channel 7, a 2.4 gHz channel.

Who picked channel 7? In addition to being a speed-limited channel, it is also an overlapped channel: https://www.metageek.com/training/resources/why-channels-1-6-11/

It is most likely that your router auto selected an overlapped, speed-limited channel for you. https://superuser.com/questions/1311149/why-do-wifi-routers-do-such-a-bad-job-of-channel-selection

I suggest that you rename the access points; something like TP-Link_15CC_2.4 and TP-Link_15CC_5. Give each segment a fixed channel, 1, 6 or 11 in the 2.4 gHz band and 36-48 or 149-161 in the 5 gHz band.

You can get an idea of which channels your neighbors are using with the terminal command:

```
nmcli device wifi list
```

Ideally, select a channel from the suggestions above that is far from your neighbors.

After making these changes, reboot the router.

At the Network Manager icon, select the 5 gHz segment, TP-Link_15CC_5 and tell us if the speeds are improved.